# Why doesn't Chrome update width of an inline-block

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, frontend

Below is a `ul` that is displayed with `display: inline-block` and has no explicit `width` set. Also, there is a `breakpoint` at `700px` to change the list from a one-column layout to a two-column layout.

I expected that at the breakpoint the list size will automatically update to it's preferred shrink-wrapped size.

In Safari and Firefox this works as I expected. As the window size increases the width of the list increases at the breakpoint.

In Chrome it does not work as I expected. As the window size increases the width of the list does not increase at the breakpoint which causes content to overlap and extend outside the list bounds.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a Chrome layout bug?

Safari:
[image]

Chrome:
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/mpvosseller/ya8Lfn56/8/

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

ul {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: lightblue;
  column-count: 2;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  ul {
    column-count: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1111111111111111111111111111111111111111</li>
  <li>2222222222222222222222222222222222222222</li>
  <li>3333333333333333333333333333333333333333</li>
  <li>4444444444444444444444444444444444444444</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: it seems to be a bug, if you inspect the element and check/uncheck the property it works fine